# Check for .Net version with WIX

Tags: .net, frameworks, wix, installation

I want to ask a question about creating installer using WIX. So, I use WIX v3.5. Is it possible to make a check for installed .NET Framework 4.6.1?

I tried it with

```
WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_461_OR_LATER_INSTALLED
```

but there is an error for Unresolved reference.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of wix instead of 3.10.3 the latest stable release which already has support for detecting .net 4.6.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue using wixh 3.5 you will probably just be best off porting the functionality from the NetFXExtension whose source you can find [here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib)

If you just copy paste the package group for NetFx461Redist and then go through the code finding all the other registry search ref and propery refs it should work. Although the easiest solution is just use wix 3.10.3 but that may required updating some legacy code that used to work in 3.5 but no longer works in the latest WiX.

Comment: Brian, would you tell me please where can I find any tutorial or something for upgrading WIX 3.5 to WIX 3.10.3?

Comment: It depends on how your build is set up. If it's just on your machine you should be able to just install the latest wix toolset on the machine and it will start using the new wix when building. If you have a binaries dir for wix, just replacing with the new binaries should work. If you run into problems, updating wix then just creating a new project and copy/paste all the source should work. This might happen if the project templates have changed between 3.5 and 3.10.3 which is entirely possible.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I created a new project and copy/paste all the source and that works. Thank you again! :)